# Call JQuery function after CSS rendering

Tags: jquery, css

When I use `$(document).ready(function() {...}`, the function is called after the DOM is ready, but (I think) before CSS styles have loaded.

I want to retrieve the width of an element, but when I try to retrieve it inside a ready() event, the value returned isn't matching the CSS value. However, when I use a timer to call this function 10 seconds later, it works as intended.

So, is there a way to listen to CSS rendering with jQuery?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a demo http://jsfiddle.net to show the problem? CSS should be loaded before DOM ready fires. Is there some animation occurring on the element, or those around it?

Comment: try $(window).load(function() { }). It fires after document ready.

Comment: Are you using external fonts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To complete my first post, I use JSF framework (Mojarra) + PrimeFaces components. My all JS is this one :

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    alert("parent : " + $("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().css("width"));

    window.setInterval(function(){alert("parent : " + $("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().css("width"));}, 5000);

});
```

and I get 416px followed 5s later by 522px.

I'm calling JS script via JSF like this :

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="styles/styles.css" />
```

And...that's all. I don't understand

Comment: Could the problem be the JSF lifecyle...?